# How to pass data from one component to TextInput of another component and still be able to edit the value in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

I passed value from a component to the TextInput of the component below and set the data to the value prop of the TextInput but I'm not able to edit the value. If I delete a text or type something in the TextInput, it get replaced immediately with the value that I passed from the first component.

Here is the code

```
export default function EditTodoScreen({ route }) {
  const { title, description } = route.params
  const [state, setState] = useState({titleToUpdate: title, title: "", description: "" });

  const {isLoading, mutateAsync} = useUpdateTodo()

  //New way of making network call
  const handleSubmitUpdatedTodo = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await mutateAsync(state)
      showToast(response.data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      showToast(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.inputHeader}>Title</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Please enter title"
          style={styles.input}
          allowFontScaling
          onChangeText={(title) => {
            setState({ ...state, title });
            {console.log(title)}
          }}
          value={title}
        />
        <Text style={styles.inputHeader}>Description</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Please enter description"
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(description) => {
            setState({ ...state, description });
          }}
          value={description}
        />
      </View>
      <Button
        buttonStyle={styles.button}
        title="submit"
        onPress={() => {
          handleSubmitUpdatedTodo()
        }}
      />
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator color="red" /> : null}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Please, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//if your state define like this
const { title, description } = route.params
const [state, setState] = useState({
  //here the value passed from component, the key is `titleToUpdate`
   titleToUpdate: title,  
   title: "", 
   description: ""
});


//you should change it by the following
onChangeText={(title) => {
   //remember the key is `titleToUpdate`
   setState({ ...state, titleToUpdate : title });     
}}

//and the input value should be 
value={state.titleToUpdate}

<TextInput
   onChangeText={(title) => {
      setState({ ...state, titleToUpdate : title });     
   }}
  value={state.titleToUpdate}
/>
```

Comment: The problem is from `value={description}` @Ahmed Gaber . Even when i commented out the hook I am still not able to edit the text in the TextInput.

Comment: Use value={state.description}  because your state is object